# How do I find the location of a system-wide path added by a program?

Tags: bash

I tried to install a program (bruker topspin) which added a permanent path. Now that I have removed the program I want to remove the path as well. But I cannot find its location.

```
echo $PATH
/home/uttam/bin:/opt/topspin3.5pl7/prog/bin/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I checked `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`. However, this `/opt/topspin3.5pl7/prog/bin/scripts` path is not listed in any of these locations.

Where else should I look?

Comment: There might also be a `~/.bash_profile`, or additional files in `/etc/profile.d`(which is the correct place for additional login environment). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
find ~/ /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l 'PATH=' {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

to get a list of all files within `~` and `/etc` that are setting `PATH` environment variable, it gives you a list of files:

```
/home/user/.profile
/etc/environment
```

You can also use:

```
find ~/ /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l 'topspin3' {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

For a better luck, with a high possibility it's going to show you the exact file which that address is being set in.

As you asked for wide system search:

```
find /  -type f -exec grep -l 'topspin3' {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

---

To do it manually, you should check these out:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc > ~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile > ~/.bash_login > ~/.profile
```

or even:

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: with the find command I got: /home/uttam/.xsession-errors
/home/uttam/.xsession-errors.old
/home/uttam/.bash_history

Comment: How can I perform a whole system search? find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l 'topspin3' {} \; 2> /dev/null returns nothing.

Comment: For wide system search: `find /  -type f -exec grep -l 'topspin3' {} \; 2> /dev/null`